# logic to split this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text,

```
              Name:Jon
               Age:25
              Gender:Male
```

how to split this to get the following result,

```
              Jon
              25
               Male
```

if i use this,

```
           var results = file.split(":");
```

i get results[0]=Name, results[1]=JonAge, results[2]=25Gender,
and when i give,

```
            var results = file.split("\n");
```

i get results[0]=Name:Jon, results[1]=Age:25,...

but i couldn't get the above, how to check for either a colon or a new line at the same time ?

Comment: You could do some string replacement before splitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split first on the newline, then the colon:

```
file.split('\n').map(function(line){return line.split(':')[1];})
```

This could be accomplished with a loop, obviously, but the `map` function makes it nice and neat.

You could also use a regular expression:

```
file.match(/[^:]+$/gm)
```

Finally, you can extend the functionality of arrays by creating a split function that works on arrays:

```
Array.prototype.split = function(s) { 
    return this.map( function(x) { return.x.split(s); } ); 
}
```

Then you can chain your splits and you'll get an array of arrays:

```
var results = file.split('\n').split(':');
console.log( 'Name: ' + results[0][1] );
console.log( 'Age: ' + results[1][1] );
console.log( 'Gender: ' + results[2][1] );
```

Your choice of method depends a lot on how "safe" you want to be.  I.e., are you concerned about malformed input or colons in the field names or values....

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Use a for loop.

```
var r = file.split("\n");
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    results[i] = r[i].split(":")[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with two steps, first you'll want to split the text by newline:

```
lines = str.split( '\n' )
```

Then iterate over each line and split each one by a colon:

```
final = {};
for ( pair in lines ){
  var split = lines[ pair ].split( ':' );

  var name = split[ 0 ].trim(); //cleaning out any whitespacve
  var value = split[ 1 ].trim(); //cleaning out any whitespacve

  final[ name ] = value;
}
```

`final` is now:

```
Object {Name: "Jon", Age: "25", Gender: "Male"}
```